# Conversão de espaços em vírgulas

Tags: delphi, matemática, conversão, byte

Estou com um aplicativo em Delphi, onde ele pega um arquivo, faz a leitura de um buffer de 1k e faz a conversão dos espaços(campo vazio " ") em vírgulas. Foi utilizado um calculo matemático onde não estou conseguindo entender muito bem, alguém poderia me explicar como funcionou

```
var
  InFile : File;//são usadas com muitas procedures e funções de I/O
  TamBuffer : array[0..1024] of Byte;//é um buffer de 1k para armazenas os dados lidos do arquivo
  PosiPointer : LongInt; // Armazena a posição do ponteiro
  LeitBytes : Integer;//Leitura de bytes
  x : Integer;
begin
  //Define o nome do arquivo para uma variável de arquivo
  AssignFile(InFile,FName);
  //Define o tamanho do registro para 1 byte
  Reset(InFile, 1);
  while not Eof(InFile) do
  begin
    //Obtém a posição do arquivo
    PosiPointer := FilePos(InFile);
    //Lê um bloco de 1k de Byte no buffer
    BlockRead(InFile, TamBuffer, Sizeof(TamBuffer), LeitBytes);
    //Converte espaçoes em vírgulas
    for x := 0 to LeitBytes-1 do
    begin
      if TamBuffer[x]=32 then TamBuffer[x]:= 44;
    end;
    //Move o ponteiro de arquivo de volta para o início do bloco
    Seek(InFile, PosiPointer);
    //Escreve o buffer de 1k byte de volta no disco
    BlockWrite(InFile, TamBuffer, LeitBytes);
  end;
  //Descarrega os buffers no disco e fecha o arquivo
  CloseFile(InFile);
  ShowMessage('Processo completo! ');
```

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/103217).  Pelo que entendi do código ele usou o valor do caractere da tabela asc (não é uma fórmula). Mas ele faz isso mesmo que descreveu. Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: minha dúvida é referente ao laço For, quero entender como ele funciona, o porque é igual a 32 e se for true porque irá receber 44

Comment: pois é, o que ele está fazendo e iterando os 1024 bytes de dados (1k), 1 caractere por vez. verificando o valor do caractere via tabela ASCII, se ele possui o char valor decimal 32 (espaço em branco) substitua pelo char decimal 44 (vírgula). Você pode verificar essa informação procurando no google por tabela ASCII.

Comment: Ok, consegui entender, obrigado